# How do I get access to INodeServices without dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I'd like to run some node code from my c#.  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices` seems to be the way to do this job however the examples are all very similar and all involve putting

```
services.AddNodeServices();
```

in the configure services function and then DI adds the implementation of INodeServices to a controller. Like this

```
public class foo  
{
    private readonly INodeServices _nodeServices;

    public foo(INodeServices nodeServices)
    {
        _nodeServices = nodeServices;
    }
}
```

As I'm using this in a class library rather than a webapi how is DI going to work?  Also how do I call the class from a unit test, what can I pass into the constructor? I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: The DI container built into ASP.NET Core is not part of ASP.NET Core. You can use it by referencing the NuGet package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Comment: You can build up the object graph yourself and build a service provider. Reference the library suggested in the previous comment and check this site for examples of how to use it in an application outside of asp.net-core.

Comment: Very useful article here [Essential .NET - Dependency Injection with .NET Core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt707534.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The concept of DI is that it can be used to resolve *object graphs*. That is, it doesn't just resolve dependencies of the Controller class, but dependencies of those dependencies, dependencies of those dependencies, etc.

To use `INodeServices` in your own library, you simply need to reference [Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices/), then accept it as a constructor parameter.

```
public class MyServiceFromMyLibrary : IMyServiceFromMyLibrary
{
    private readonly INodeServices nodeServices;

    public MyServiceFromMyLibrary(INodeServices nodeServices)
    {
        this.nodeServices = nodeServices;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then reference your library from the Web API project and inject your service into a controller.

```
public class FooController  
{
    private readonly IMyServiceFromMyLibrary myService;

    public FooController(IMyServiceFromMyLibrary myService)
    {
        this.myService = myService;
    }
}
```

DI takes care of putting the `INodeServices` instance into your class provided it is registered in your [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/), as follows.

```
services.AddNodeServices();
services.AddTransient<IMyServiceFromMyLibrary, MyServiceFromMyLibrary>();
```

If your end game is to create a *reusable library* rather than an *application layer* refer to [DI Friendly Library](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/) for some techniques to make your library easier to use *without* the use of dependency injection.

> Also how do I call the class from a unit test, what can I pass into the constructor?

For a unit test, you would just need to mock `INodeServices`. The simplest way is to use a mocking library, such as [`Moq`](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart).

```
var mock = new Mock<INodeServices>();
mock.Setup(ns => ns.InvokeAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(...);

var target = new MyServiceFromMyLibrary(mock.Object);
// .. Call a method on target and then assert the results
```

References:

- [Using Node Services in ASP.NET Core](https://dotnetthoughts.net/using-node-services-in-aspnet-core/)
- [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but It's not really helped me, the techniques for hiding DI revolve around newing up the INodeServices do you know what the constructor is?

Comment: also I suppose I meant integration test rather than strictly unit test as I want to test what the NodeServices does rather than mock it out.

Comment: Since .NET Core is open source, this is pretty easy to determine - it looks like you should be able to use [NodeServicesFactory](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/fb19ee8923b5ef7ebb125bc6e5a1a182cfadfe88/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices/Configuration/NodeServicesFactory.cs). However, its dependency `NodeServicesOptions` depends on `IServiceFactory` (making it a service locator), and it looks like there are several other things that depends on.

Comment: Bottom line is that unit testing is straightforward, but integration testing not so much. See [Integration testing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing).